Define a type for strings that are keys in an object
I have a country configuration which looks as such:
type CountryConfig = {
   [country: string]: {
      countryCode: string,
      callingCode: string,
      ...
   }
}

const balkanCountries: CountryConfig = {
   Albania: { countryCode: "AL", callingCode: "+355", ... },
   Bulgaria: { countryCode: "BG", callingCode: "+359", ... },
   Croatia: { countryCode: "HR", callingCode: "+385", ... },
   ...
}

I want to create a type from the keys of balkanCountries:
type BalkanCountry = keyof typeof balkanCountries

Expected type: BalkanCountry = "Albania" | "Bulgaria" | "Croatia" | ..., actual type: BalkanCountry = string | number.
Based on the answer in this Stack Overflow thread this is expected behaviour and I can get around the number type by explicitly extracting the string as such:
type BalkanCountry = Extract<keyof typeof balkanCountries, string>

However, the output type I get is still type BalkanCountries = string and not a union of literals.
This means I can do assignment as:
const currentCountry: BalkanCountry = "Spain" // typescript will not throw error

Why this is happening? How can I ensure currentCountry can only be a value that is a key in balkanCountries?
Note: I am using TypeScript ~5.0.4.

Use satisfies, not an annotation

You will have to drop the type definition to infer the keys from the object.
const balkanCountries = {
   Albania: { countryCode: "AL", callingCode: "+355" },
   Bulgaria: { countryCode: "BG", callingCode: "+359",  },
   Croatia: { countryCode: "HR", callingCode: "+385",  },
} satisifies CountryConfig;

type BalkanCountry = keyof typeof balkanCountries
// "Albania" | "Bulgaria" | "Croatia"

The satisfies operator (introduced in TS 4.9), will ensure the type safety.
TS playground

Thanks Matthieu! This worked! Do you mind explaining why? I've never used satisfies before so this is quite new to me.

This ensures typesafety witouth forcing the type. if you define balkanCountries: CountryConfig, it will check the type CountryConfig not the values.
